# Function not defined even in <script> reference

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that sends a message to discord. But when i click it it says SendMessage() is not defined.

Ive tried added the script tag in the head, body, and even the raw code inside it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ppzjmxw48x

My entire project is in there.

its only manager.html

It shows this

ReferenceError
SendMessage is not defined
manager.html:189:67

Comment: As far as I can see SendMessage is never defined. Are you supposed to make it? Are you supposed to import it? Where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: Opened the project, can't find the code we need to debug. In particular I can't find the function that isn't defined, thus it is undefined

Comment: `SendMessage()` is defined in `DBScript/GuiCommands.js`

Comment: Its in DbScripts/GuiCommands.js

Comment: ...it didn't occur to me to check **DB**Scripts for this command. But I suppose in this case it stands for **D**iscord**B**ot.

Comment: Yes Thats Exactly what it means

Answer (score 1):

In `main.js`, `GuiCommands.js` is loaded with

```
var Skript = require("./GuiCommands.js");
```

`require` returns an object containing all the exported functions and variables, so the `SendMessage()` function becomes a property of `Skript`.

So you have to use `Skript.SendMessage()`, not just `SendMessage()` here:

```
<button onClick="Skript.SendMessage()" id="button" class="sendmsg">Send Message</button>
```

Comment: In main.js?  Because that works, just when i press the button.

Comment: I mean in the `onclick` attribute. That's where the error is happening, isn't it?

Comment: Line 181 Manager.html, thats where

Comment: That line is `<button onClick="SendMessage()" id="button" class="sendmsg">Send Message</button>`, which is what I just said.

Comment: Where is it loaded with The require?

Comment: From `var Skript = require("./GuiCommands.js")`, which is in `main.js`. That makes all the exported functions be properties of the `Skript` object.

Comment: No it doesnt..... i only used that to attempt to makesure the bot is loaded before you can send a message.